# File not saved using JFileChooser in Java

Tags: java, swing, file, filepath, jfilechooser

Iam a java beginner. 
I have written a simple program to write some contents to a file using showSaveDialoge() in JFileChooser. The code including below.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
    {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();   
        try {
            File file = new File("fileName.txt");
            fc.setSelectedFile(file);
            int r = fc.showSaveDialog(frame);   
            if(r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {   
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);   
                writer.append("Data inside the file");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
            else if(r == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("Do nothing for CANCEL");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be written, try again.");
        }
    }
```

the code gets executed and Save Dialogue box has come. But when I click SAVE button on Dialogue box, nothing had happening. The file has not saved in the selected location. What may be the reason.? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is hapenning is:

you create a File in your current location with name fileName.txt

```
File file = new File("fileName.txt"); //could be $HOME$/fileName.txt
```

User selects ProgramFiles/file.txt

but you uses on FileWritter file information, not what user chossed from FileChooser.

change

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

to

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fc.getSelectedFile());
```

It should write to selected file from file chooser.

You were writing to fileName.txt which will be saved in current directory from which you run program.